# Why isn't npm installing dependencies when I have an item inside devDependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I remove the devDependencies array, trimArguments installs fine. If I give it a dev-dependency, it seems to completely ignore trimArguments. No warning, just silent failure. My package.json is the following:

```
{"name":"asyncFuture",
 "version":"0.1.0",
 "main": "asyncFuture.js",
 "dependencies":[
    "git+https://git@github.com/fresheneesz/trimArguments.git#578afe0fa6ce96797c36e018bf5bae31b508a02f"
 ],
 "devDependencies": [
    "git+https://git@github.com/fresheneesz/deadunit.git#8395e438492267b94ef51ee4f94a6d6c8f1c15da"
 ],
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git://github.com/fresheneesz/asyncFuture"
 }
}
```

Is this an NPM bug or am I misunderstanding how to use this? NPM version 1.3.8 on windows 7 32-bit

**UPDATE**

It's looking like npm is ignoring any package except for the last one, even if I put all dependencies under the "dependencies" array (and get rid of devDependencies). This has to be a bug. I'm gonna file a ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [URLs as dependencies](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#URLs-as-Dependencies):

> You may specify a [...] URL in place of a **version range**.

Noting that [`dependencies`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies) are:

> specified with a simple hash of ***package name*** to **version range**.

You still need to specify the package name even when using a (Git) URL.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "trimArguments": "git+https://git@github.com/fresheneesz/trimArguments.git#578afe0fa6ce96797c36e018bf5bae31b508a02f"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "deadunit": "git+https://git@github.com/fresheneesz/deadunit.git#8395e438492267b94ef51ee4f94a6d6c8f1c15da"
  }
```

Comment: If I need to specify a package name, then I would expect it to not correctly install either of them. It is correctly installing one of them, just not the other. But I'll try this as a work around. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work : ) - I still think its a bug in npm (and I wrote a ticket for it)

Answer (score 2):

`dependencies` and `devDependencies` are not arrays; they are maps.

https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies

Comment: Except that I've been using them as arrays for every other project, and they work fine...

Comment: Please show a single published npm package which does this successfully. As one of the npm maintainers, this seems implausible.

Comment: npm install https://github.com/fresheneesz/examplePackage/tarball/16ef50a7861e776724458781d5dcd169976b4f8f - you can use the package or run examplePackage/test/test.js

Comment: I guess its not *published* per se.. but it certainly works properly